# moviePlayer - Black screen appears after finished playing

Tags: ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

The problem I'm having is that when I press the **done button** or the movie **finish playing** a black screen appears. I would like to get back to the start screen where I placed a UIImage.

```
-(void)playMovie:(id)sender
{

    NSString * str=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"yo2" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL * url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];
    MPMoviePlayerController * movieController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    movieController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [movieController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:movieController.view];
    [movieController prepareToPlay];
    [movieController play];
    _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                     initWithContentURL:url];


    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayer];


}



- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

    // Remove observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:^{
                                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"back" sender:self];
                             }];

}

@end
```

Comment: That sounds as if your notification handler is not being invoked at all when the user presses the "Done" button, correct?

Comment: Yes something like that. When I press done the movie just disappears. And the the black screen shows. Any ideas?